# Replace 1 gang 2 way with 2 gang 2 way

Tags: wiring, lighting, switch, light-fixture

I currently have downstairs in the hall, a 2 gang 2 way switch that has 5 wires, two red wires coming from 1 cable, and 3 wires (red, blue, yellow) coming from a second cable and they are wired to control both the hall light and the landing light.

On the landing, i have a **1 gang** 2 way switch with the same as downstairs 5 wires, wired to only control the landing light. 1 of the 2 red wires and the yellow wire are connected to L1, the 2nd of the 2 red wires and the blue wire are connected to L2, and the red wire from the cable with the blue and yellow wires is connected to only 1 of the common terminals.

is it possible with this wiring to replace the landing's switch with a 2 gang 2 way switch to allow both the landing, and the hall to be able to control both sets of lights?

if so, a coloured diagram would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you located? These colors seem odd.

Comment: based in the UK

Comment: Adding a coloured diagram of the current wiring might be useful. [Here's what I got based on your description](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BQE8l.png).